# Implementing pull-to-refresh in Flutter with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, pull-to-refresh, riverpod

I am new to Riverpod and trying to implement pull to refresh with Riverpod in my Flutter app and can't seem to find any good tutorial online. Has anyone implemented pull-to-refresh in their Flutter app while using Riverpod. I have looked for tutorials everywhere, but most I found was simple network request on app load. Thanks in advance!

using these dependencies for riverpod and network requests.
flutter_riverpod: ^0.12.1
dio: ^3.0.10

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `context.refresh(yourProvider)` in your refresh action.  Works great.

In Riverpod 1.0.0 and above, you can use `ref.refresh(yourProvider)`

Comment: Just to clarify a little bit:
In riverpod 1.0.0 you should use `ref.refresh(yourFutureProvider.future)` because `.refresh()` is expecting `ProviderBase<Future<void>>` argument type.

Comment: Actually not: if you `ref.refresh(yourFutureProvider.future)` because you specified `<T>` in `final yourFutureProvider = FutureProvider<T>(....)` it don't recall the future at least you use a state notifier i guess.

Instead if you define the provider without specifying `<T>`, you can call refresh using `ref.refresh(yourFutureProvider)`

Comment: Here one example with a most recent release of Riverpod

```ref
            .refresh(upComingMoviesStateNotifierProvider.notifier)
            .getNextUpcomingMoviesPage()```

Comment: And in Riverpod 2, ref.invalidate is preferred, as they will not "stack up" during the calculate phase... just one rebuild will be triggered if anyone is watching, and none otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Turned out the *working* way of pull-to-refresh the UI using Riverpod (^1.0.0) is this:

Provider:

```
final yourFutureProvider = FutureProvider<T>(....);
```

Inside the Build method:

```
                  return RefreshIndicator(
                    onRefresh: () async {
                      return await ref.refresh(yourFutureProvider);
                    },
```

Answer (score 1):

**THIS WORKED FOR ME**

```
Declare the provider
```

```html
final sessionsProvider = FutureProvider<List<Session>>((ref) async {
  final sessionServices = ref.read(sessionsServiesProvider);
  return await sessionServices.getSessions();
});
```

```
add refresh indicator
```

```html
RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async => ref.refresh(sessionsProvider),
        child: ...)
```